# Spring+SockJS+Stomp not receiving messages other than heartbeat

Tags: bower, stomp, spring-websocket, sockjs

I am using Spring version 4.3.6.RELEASE on server side and bower clients "stomp-websocket": "2.0" and "sockjs-client": "1.1.4"

Here is all relevant code on server side -

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer
{
  @Autowired
  private SimpMessagingTemplate brokerMessagingTemplate;

  @Override
  public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry)
  {
    // for local testing, setting allowed origins to * - Should be removed later
    registry.addEndpoint("/websoc").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS().setSupressCors(true);
  }

  @Override
  public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry)
  {
    registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic", "/queue");
  }

  @Override
  public void configureClientOutboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration)
  {
    registration.taskExecutor()
    .corePoolSize(10)
    .maxPoolSize(20);
  }

  @Override
  public void configureWebSocketTransport(WebSocketTransportRegistration registration)
  {
    registration.setSendTimeLimit( 15 * 1000)
    .setSendBufferSizeLimit( 512 * 1024)
    .setMessageSizeLimit( 128 * 1024);
  }

  @PostConstruct
  public void fetchNotifications()
  {

    NotificationsController.setMesgingTmpt(brokerMessagingTemplate);
  }
}


@Controller
public class NotificationsController
{
  private static SimpMessagingTemplate brokerMessagingTemplate;

  public static void setMesgingTmpt(SimpMessagingTemplate tmp)
  {
    brokerMessagingTemplate = tmp;
  }

  // @SendTo("/topic/userNotifications")
  public void testWSMessage(JUserNotification un)
  {
    LOGGER.debug("testWSMessage called");

    un.setAccountId("1");
    un.setUserId("1");

    try
    {
      LOGGER.debug("sending notif: {}", JSONUtils.stringify(un));
      brokerMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/userNotifications", un);

    } catch (final Exception e)
    {
      LOGGER.debug("exception while sending msg to client: {}", e);
    }
   // return un;
  }
}

@Component
public class CustomApplicationListener implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationEvent>
{
    @Override
  public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent event)
  {
    if (event instanceof SessionSubscribeEvent)
    {
      LOGGER.debug("subscribe event received. Some params - ");
      final SessionSubscribeEvent se = (SessionSubscribeEvent) (event);
      final StompHeaderAccessor headers = StompHeaderAccessor.wrap(se.getMessage());
      LOGGER.debug("sessionId: {}", headers.getSessionId());
      LOGGER.debug("sessionAttributes: {}", headers.getSessionAttributes());
      LOGGER.debug("ack: {}", headers.getAck());
      LOGGER.debug("command: {}", headers.getCommand());
      LOGGER.debug("destination: {}", headers.getDestination());
      LOGGER.debug("subscriptionId: {}", headers.getSubscriptionId());
      LOGGER.debug("user: {}", headers.getUser());


      // test code
      final NotificationsController notifs = new NotificationsController();
      final JUserNotification usrNotif = new JUserNotification();
      notifs.testWSMessage(usrNotif);
    }
  }
}
```

On the client, this is the code -

```
    this.set("webSockURL", this.get("serverInfo").getWebsocketEndPoint());
    this.set("sock", new SockJS(this.get("webSockURL")));
    this.set("stompClient", Client.over(this.get("sock")));

    var stompcli = this.get("stompClient");

    var subscribeCallBack = function(message) {
    console.log("inside subscribeCallBack");
      this._processNotifications(message)
    };

    var connectCallBack = function() {
      console.log("inside connectCallBack");
      stompcli.subscribe("topic/userNotifications", subscribeCallBack);
    };

    stompcli.connect({}, {}, connectCallBack);
```

Websocket connect gets established and I receive the heartbeat messages but I do not receive the notifications that I am sending. I have even tried using the @SendTo annotation and it doesn't work.

When I try the same server code with webjars stomp and sockjs and run it locally, I get the messages. This gets me thinking that it is the client libraries that have a problem, but am unsure about it.

The server runs on a docker container behind nginx as reverse proxy. I have configured the ELB to allow websockets and enabled proxy_protocol too.

Since the connection itself is established successfully, I don't doubt the infrastructure part of it. 
Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Comment: `stompcli.connect({}, connectCallBack);`

Comment: The client library that I use requires 2 parameters, I have tried both and only stompcli.connect({}, {}, connectCallBack); works

Comment: Oh, i see. I think you are using this one http://jmesnil.net/stomp-websocket/doc/, so my comment is misleading, sorry.

Comment: also check topic name, you dont have leading slash here- "topic/userNotifications". Maybe should be "/topic/userNotifications"? I am not familiar with your library, does it add leading slash on subscribe?

Comment: Wow! That did the trick. Thanks. The documentation is misleading - it specifies the leading / in some methods and does not in others. If you could add this as an answer, I will gladly accept it.

Comment: @user1516873 I have a follow up problem while sending messages to specific user. I have posted it as a separate question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49482735/cannot-send-messages-to-unauthenticated-users-using-springstompsockjs. Will be glad if you could take a look at it

Answer (score 0):

You are write `topic/userNotifications` without `/` before  **topic** so try rewrite javascript code to be look like below code :

```
stompcli.subscribe("/topic/userNotifications", subscribeCallBack);
```